# Woocommerce Plugin Error Message (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce

Currently getting the following error message on my site built with Wordpress on woocommerce.

***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /home4/name/public_html/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/webappick-product-feed-for-woocommerce/includes/classes/class-woo-feed-products.php on line 674***

This is the line it's referring too with the error, however, I cannot see any error with it?

```
$imgIds=!empty($ids=$this->getAttributeValue($Id,"_product_image_gallery"))?explode(",",$ids):"";
```

Could anyone shed any light on what the error with this line is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty` function always expects a variable as parameter not a condition.

instead of `empty($ids=$this->getAttributeValue($Id,"_product_image_gallery"))` try `empty($this->getAttributeValue($Id,"_product_image_gallery"))` that should work for you.

Comment: That gives the following error - "Can't use method return value in write context "

Comment: then do that in prev line... but not in ternary operator, or as a param of empty function